# python add file logging from multiple modules - new file for every request

Tags: python, flask, logging, filehandler

I have a service running on flask inside docker, that recieves requests.
For every request, i want to export a log file including all logs from all modules in the way.
Right now, it is logging constantly to stream using basicConfig, and its great.
However, I need to add a fileHandler for every request(different file path)

I added the fileHandler when a request arrives in requestHandler.py, and remove the handler when request is handled. This works, file is created properly, but the problem is it does not apply in other modules for some reason. it is only logging to file from the module that created the handler.

Reading the docs, logging states it should be global:

"  **Using logging in multiple modules**

Multiple calls to logging.getLogger('someLogger') return a reference to the same logger
object. This is true not only within the same module, but also across modules as long as it
is in the same Python interpreter process. It is true for references to the same object;
additionally, application code can define and configure a parent logger in one module and
create (but not configure) a child logger in a separate module, and all logger calls to the
child will pass up to the parent. Here is a main module:  "

My Modules Setup:

main.py

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format=config.LOG_FORMAT)
logger = logging.getLogger()
```

requestHandler.py

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def add_file_logging(self):
    for hdlr in logger.handlers[:]:  # remove the existing file handlers
        if isinstance(hdlr, logging.FileHandler):
            logger.removeHandler(hdlr)
    fh = logging.FileHandler(filename=self.log_file_path)
    fh.setFormatter(config.LOG_FORMAT)
    fh.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logger.addHandler(fh)
    logger.info("Added file handler : {}".format(self.log_file_path))
```

other_module.py

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

- Console logging works great
- File logging include only one log line from requestHandler.py
- The loop for deleting handlers is empty - it does not detect any handlers, but the idea is that it should replace the old file handler with the new one.

**Please help if you have a solution or a better approach for this feature.
Thanks!:)**